# Filter message in mule

Tags: filter, mule

I want to pass certain messages to go through the logic,
Suppose if (flowVars.status ==x or flowVars.status ==y), it should not be passed.
Any ideas how I can implement this in mule with filter or any other component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an expression filter for that.

```
<expression-filter expression="#[!(flowVars['status'] == 'X' || flowVars['status'] == 'Y')]" doc:name="Do not Process status of X and Y"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Choice Connector as well, based on the value of status it will either follow a default path or skip it.

```
 <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="flowVars.status=='x' || flowVars.name=='y'">
                <logger message="#['Condition Matched , Skipping the processing']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <logger message="#['Default condition']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
```